# jQuery changing .get file runtime

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have used the following code to plot a graph using an xml in jquery:

```
var $xml_name = 'data.xml';
myfunction($xml_name);
function myfunction($xml_name) {
   $.get($xml_name, function (xml) {
        // (some code)
   });
});
```

I want to change the value of $xml_name on change in selected value from a dropdown.
For that I used the following code

```
$('#DropDown_Name').change(function () {
    $xml_name = $('newdata.xml');
    myfunction($xml_name); 
})
```

But on changing the value of drop down the graph is not refreshing.
Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you pass string into your function:

```
var $xml_name = 'data.xml';
```

While on your dropdown change you pass jquery object

```
$xml_name = $('newdata.xml');
```

I don't think that is a correct behaviour.

Comment: This seems like the right answer.  Is $xml_name the nAme of a corresponding file name?  If so, it should be a string instead of an object.  And is $new_data.xml a dynamic file name related to the element?  If so you could store the dynamic file name as a data attribute of the selected option like "data-fname=...".